# Is there any method to clean the website unused resources

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

Is there any method to clean the website unused resources like...

1. CSS that are no more used in the website
2. skins that are no more than in the website
3. images that are no more than in the website
4. Javascript function that are no more used in the website

this thing require, when website is completed and ready for deployment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a firefox add-on [Dust-Me Selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5392) that will find unused CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about doing it in Visual Studio other than doing a Find In Solution for each CSS rule / Skin / Image.

To find unused CSS rules, you could use the [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) add-on for the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) add-on for [Firefox](http://www.mozilla-europe.org/en/firefox/). This will analyse individual pages of your site and give you a load of info on how to speed it up, including removing unused CSS rules. Might be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with looking the pages once they're rendered, in case selectors are used in code but not rendered in the final pages due to conditions during execution.

I can't think of anything other than an old fashioned find/replace in the code-behinds because a program would have to have syntactical knowledge of the tags, but if they're being built with, they'll probably be strings.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer by abmv wasn't correct at that time (end of 2009 - but thanks for mentioning it!), the **current** version of my software [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) does support CSS, thus it will detect such orphans :-) However it won't help for Javascript functions, only links to script files.